# Plot a step (piecewise constant) function in R

Tags: r

Suppose you have the following sample dataset:

```
rm(list=ls()); set.seed(1)
start<-c(0:4); stop<-c(1:5); Response<- round(10*runif(5) )
Dat<-data.frame(start,stop,Response)
Dat
  start stop Response
1     0    1 3
2     1    2 4
3     2    3 6
4     3    4 9
5     4    5 2
```

The start/stop is the x-axis. How can I make a plot in R such that between a certain start and stop the y axis takes the constant value in response. i.e. from time 0 to 1 the y-axis takes the value 3, ... ,from time 4 to 5 the y-axis takes the value 2.

Comment: `plot(Response ~ start, type = "s", data = Dat)` is a good start

Comment: This helps but does not plot the last step function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are either of these what you're looking for?

```
library(ggplot2)

Dat %>% 
    ggplot(aes(start, Response)) +
    geom_step()

Dat %>% 
    ggplot() +
    geom_segment(aes(x = start, xend = stop, y = Response, yend = Response))
```

Comment: The second code works. The first code does not plot the last step function i.e when start =4 to stop =5.